# Fill in the 'missing' values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Python and I do not know how to solve this problem. Maybe someone can help me with a solution.

For every value in cloumn `x` I would like to have the numbers from 1 - 400 in column `y`. Column `x` should stay the same (400 times). In my dataframe this is almost the case, but some values in this range are randomly missing and should be added. Every other column has to be 0.

This is my df:

```
      x         y        value
0       20       1        8.046723    
1       20       2        4.613252     
2       20       3       14.546438     
3       20       4        0.000000        
4       20       8        2.285226                  
...    ...     ...             ...                     
2987    29     394        0.000000                   
2988    29     396        0.000000                     
2989    29     397        0.000000                   
2990    29     398        0.000000                    
2991    29     400        0.000000
```

Afterwards it should look like:

```
      x         y        value
0       20       1        8.046723    
1       20       2        4.613252     
2       20       3       14.546438     
3       20       4        0.000000
4       20       5        0.000000
5       20       6        0.000000
6       20       7        0.000000           
7       20       8        2.285226                  
...    ...     ...             ...                     
3194    29     394        0.000000
3195    29     395        0.000000                                    
3196    29     396        0.000000                     
3197    29     397        0.000000                   
3198    29     398        0.000000
3199    29     399        0.000000                                        
3200    29     400        0.000000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us set the index of the dataframe to columns `x` and `y` then use `pd.MultiIndex.from_product` to create a new index where for each unique value in `x`, `y` contains all the required values, finally `reindex` the dataframe on this newly created index:

```
out = df.set_index(['x', 'y'])
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([s.index.levels[0], range(1, 401)], names=['x', 'y'])
out = out.reindex(idx, fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

---

```
>>> out

      x    y      value
0    20    1   8.046723
1    20    2   4.613252
2    20    3  14.546438
3    20    4   0.000000
4    20    5   0.000000
5    20    6   0.000000
6    20    7   0.000000
7    20    8   2.285226
8    20    9   0.000000
...  ... ...   ...
794  29  395   0.000000
795  29  396   0.000000
796  29  397   0.000000
797  29  398   0.000000
798  29  399   0.000000
799  29  400   0.000000
```